# Add/Remove Class of Nav Objects on Page Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change classes of objects in my navbar on scroll for a website I am developing. Basically, when I scroll to certain parts of a webpage I want the links to appear active and to remove the active class when they have been scrolled over.

I have managed to get the links to appear active but can't get it too remove the class. This is what I have so far but it isn't working:

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#cards').position().top) {
    $("#navcard").addClass("active");;
  } else {
    $("navcard").removeClass("active")
  }
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#projects').position().top) {
    $("#navprojects").addClass("active");;
  } else {
    $("navprojects").removeClass("active")
  }
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#dave').position().top) {
    $("#navdave").addClass("active");;
  } else {
    $("navdave").removeClass("active")
  }
})
```

```css
#cards,
#projects,
#dave {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navacard">My navacard</div>
<div id="navprojects">My navprojects</div>
<div id="navdave">My navdave</div>
<br>
<div id="cards">My navacard</div>
<div id="projects">My navprojects</div>
<div id="dave">My navdave</div>
```

I hope someone can help.

Edit: this is what is now happening:

[image: Scroll]

Comment: quickly scanning, i'm seeing missing # for these element names to select ids

Comment: You are missing the hashtag `#` on all the `JQuery` selectors when removing classes, i.e, `$("navcard").removeClass("active")` should be `$("#navcard").removeClass("active")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the `#` in the removeClass parts:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#cards').position().top) {
    $("#navcard").addClass("active");;
  } else {
    $("#navcard").removeClass("active")
  }
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#projects').position().top) {
    $("#navprojects").addClass("active");;
  } else {
    $("#navprojects").removeClass("active")
  }
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#dave').position().top) {
    $("#navdave").addClass("active");;
  } else {
    $("#navdave").removeClass("active")
  }
})
```

### Update

Try changing your code to this and let me know what the results of each `console.log` is:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {

  console.log($(this).scrollTop());
  console.log($('#cards').position().top);
  console.log($('#projects').position().top);
  console.log($('#dave').position().top);

  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#cards').position().top) {
    $("#navcard").addClass("active");;
  } else {
    $("#navcard").removeClass("active")
  }
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#projects').position().top) {
    $("#navprojects").addClass("active");;
  } else {
    $("#navprojects").removeClass("active")
  }
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#dave').position().top) {
    $("#navdave").addClass("active");;
  } else {
    $("#navdave").removeClass("active")
  }
})
```

Comment: I have now done this and it does remove the elements but not in the way I want, I'll attach a gif at the bottom of my answer to show what I mean

Comment: @AlexHawking if you want help for your question, you shouldn't downvote answers. ever...  If my answer doesn't work for you, you can just let me know and I will update.

Comment: I didn't downvote it....? I'm unsure who did. Also I tried to delete this question and rephrase it. I'm sorry someone downvoted your answer I'll upvote it for you.

Comment: @AlexHawking No worries!  I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure how to help you now.

Comment: (I didn't downvote) Answers on typo questions usually get badly received because they are typo questions - flagging to close is usually the way to go.

Comment: @AlexHawking It's possible that the `$(this).scrollTop()` is always resulting in an amount larger than the element's position, which means the `else` parts won't trigger.  Can you try `console.log($(this).scrollTop())` and a `console.log` for each element position?

Comment: Could you add the code to your answer please, I'm new to javascript and jquery so will probably do something wrong...

Comment: It returns: 0, 72.09375, 1241.09375 and 1831.09375